# assign permission to the directly using root level access in php

Tags: php, permissions, fileserver

I am developing an application which is having 2 servers. **The first one is Web Server**, where I save my PHP files and **another one is File Server** where I am storing all the files uploaded by the user.

I want to assign the write permission to directory at runtime so that I can upload the file and after uploading the file I need to change its permission to its previous state.

When I tried `chomod(FILE_PATH, 0755)`. It shows me an error. `Assign write permission as root`. I have the administrator level credentials of File Server.

What I want is to "**Grant permission 777 to the directory by logging in as `root` at runtime**"

Kindly help if there is any code sample available. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4168179/allowing-php-to-execute-a-bash-script-with-root-permissions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do NOT want to have your server logging in as `root`. Let me say that again. You really do NOT want your webserver to be logged on as root. If you did that, anyone that got control of PHP could do anything at all on the server. It is seriously unadvisable.

What you want to do is change the owner of the folder to either be the webserver, or assign it into the same group so that the webserver can happily change your folder options and the like.

You can use `sudo chown username somedir` to change the owner. This [article](http://www.tuxfiles.org/linuxhelp/fileowner.html) might also help clear up permissions for you.

Edit: Try [this blog post](http://www.trainsignal.com/blog/linux-file-permissions) for a fairly good broad-ranging article on linux permissions.

Comment: `What you want to do is change the owner of the folder to either be the webserver, or assign it into the same group so that the webserver can happily change your folder options and the like.` How?

Comment: @ArunJain I added the method to the answer.

Comment: Thanks Fluffeh, +1 vote but it did not worked for me :(   Is there any kind of tutorial available?

Comment: @ArunJain Added a decent link to the answer.