# Cannot execute python script from php

Tags: php, python

I am on a raspberry pi. The permissions of all the files including the python script which looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from time import sleep
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
GPIO.setup(11, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.output(11, False)
sleep(0.4)
GPIO.output(11, True)
sleep(1.6)
GPIO.output(11, False)
sleep(1)
```

is all owned by `www-data` and all the files are set to 777 (Yes, I know this is not smart but I'm trying to fix it this.)
It is run using sudo and my visudo file is here:

```
www-data ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /var/www/gateopener.py /usr/bin/python /bin/chmod
```

And here is the PHP...

```
<?php
if (($_POST["safe2"]) != "good") {
    header("Location: http://xx.xxx.xx.xxx/index.html");
}
ignore_user_abort(true);
set_time_limit(0);
`/usr/bin/sudo /var/www/gateopener.py`;
?>
```

Now someone tell me why the hell this isn't working? I have tried different variations of it (EI moving the file around, using different permissions.). I have tried using php's `exec()` function as well...Help me please.

Comment: how do you know it isnt working? why not put a print at the top of your python file or create a file ... to see if its getting called ...

Comment: Did you tried this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4168179/allowing-php-to-execute-a-bash-script-with-root-permissions

Comment: Have you made the python file executable?

Comment: @JoranBeasley Because I'm using the GPIO and I have been working with this for over an hour...I've tried many things/

Comment: Yes The python file is an executable that I can call from the command line. @EL3PHANTEN

Comment: @user8786264 but you have no idea what part the error is in ... because you have no feedback ... if you knew the file was calling maybe you could capture stdout/stderr to a log file to see why the script was failing ... my guess is it is permissions of `/sys/class/gpio/##` (I think thats the gpio path)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**run_me_as_daemon.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from time import sleep
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import os
while True:
   if not os.path.exists("open_gate.txt"):continue
   os.remove("open_gate.txt")   # FILE DELETE !!! so we dont re-enter
   with open("log.txt","w") as f:
     print >>f,"Opening GATE @ %s"%(time.strftime("%x %X"),)
     GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
     print >>f, "Set Mode To %s"%(GPIO.BOARD,)
     GPIO.setup(11, GPIO.OUT)
     print >>f, "SET 11 to %s"%(GPIO.OUT) 
     GPIO.output(11, False)
     print >> f,"output low signal 11"
     sleep(0.4)
     GPIO.output(11, True)
     print >> f,"output high signal to 11"
     sleep(1.6)
     GPIO.output(11, False)
     print >> f,"output low signal 11"
     sleep(1)
     print >> f,"Competed TASK"
```

**index.php**

```
<?php
if (($_POST["safe2"]) != "good") {
    header("Location: http://xx.xxx.xx.xxx/index.html");
}
file_put_contents("open_gate.txt"," ");
?>
```

is one possible solution

Comment: Okey. But should the file not be deleted after the script has run?

Comment: it deletes it as soon as it encounters it ... but it may be smart to move it to the end in case the user refreshed the php page

Comment: How would i launch this as a daemon? and thank you so much I can't wait to try this and see if it works! :) @JoranBeasley

Comment: I just tried this...It did not work. Maybe i did something wrong i dont know.

Comment: it should work ... did the output log.txt file show up?  did open_gate.txt show up ... you may want to use an absolute path for open_gate.txt in both scripts in case they are looking in different directories...  to run it as daemon just invoke it from your startup script to run in the background

or manually call it `# python my_script.py` and watch as it runs ...

Comment: Thank you. I based the solution off of this. @Joran

Comment: as an aside this means you can just run the daemon at an elevated permission level and lock your system back down ...